# NullReference Error while assiging values of Modeltype in MVC View (Razor)

Tags: vb.net, razor, model-view-controller, model

I have the following MVC

**Model:**

```
Public Class Employee
    Public Property EmployeeID As Integer
End Class
```

**Controller:**

```
Namespace Controllers
    Public Class EmployeeController
        Inherits Controller
        Function Details() As ActionResult
            Dim employee As Employee
            employee = New Employee
            employee.EmployeeID = 101
            Return View()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**View:**

```
@ModelType MVCDemo.Employee
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Employee Details"
End Code
<h2>Employee Details</h2>
<table style="font-family:Arial">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.EmployeeID
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My Problem:**
Running the code I get the following error:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

For the line:

> Line 11:             @Model.EmployeeID

I just do not know why there is no object reference. I get intellisense for the Model in the razor code. The initialiation and assigning the value to the property is ok. Mybe I am just blind, could anyone help me why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the model instance to the view:

```
Function Details() As ActionResult
    Dim employee As Employee
    employee = New Employee
    employee.EmployeeID = 101
    Return View(employee)
End Function
```

Comment: Ah, that was it. Thank you very much it is workin now! Perfect!